# Java Applet failing to clear text onscreen

Tags: java, swing, applet

So I have this code below, and I am trying to refresh the text onscreen to show the current time. So far, I have tried using `drawRect` as a way to clear, yet the text would stay there, not updating. `super.paint` also didn't work. As well, would I incorporate that new statement into the init() or paint() methods?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.geom.*;
public class HelloWorldApplet extends javax.swing.JApplet {
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int second = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
String greeting;
String currentTime = ("The time currently is: " + hour + ":" + minute + " and" + second + " seconds");
String currentDate = ("Date: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year);


public void init() {
    greeting = "Hello World";
     Font myFont = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 20);
     // set the component or graphics object like this:
     setFont(myFont);

}
public void paint(Graphics screen){

        Graphics2D screen2D = (Graphics2D) screen;
        screen2D.drawString(greeting, 20, 50);
        screen2D.drawString(currentTime, 20, 75);
        screen2D.drawString(currentDate, 20, 100);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //DoNothing. Pretend it didnt happen...
        } 




}
public void setup(Graphics screen) {
    for (int x = 1; x < 2000000000;) {
        x++;
        repaint();

}
}
```

}

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks). _Don't_ sleep on the EDT; _do_ see [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>@trashgod already explained the most important things, but I will repeat them in my answer so it is more complete</sub>

---

1. Override `paintComponent()`, not `paint()`
2. Create a new JPanel class that does the painting for you
3. Get the time in your `paintComponent()` method, or it will always stay the same
4. Use a timer instead of sleeping the Event Dispatch Thread
5. Call `super.paintComponent()` to clear the screen

So here is the fixed code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class HelloWorldApplet extends javax.swing.JApplet {

    String greeting;

    Font myFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20);

    public void init() {

        greeting = "Hello World";

        add(new MyPanel());

        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                repaint();

            }       
        };

        Timer timer = new Timer(500, actionListener);
        timer.start();


    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics screen) {

            super.paintComponent(screen);

            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            int second = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
            int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            String currentTime = ("The time currently is: " + hour + ":" + minute
                    + " and " + second + " seconds");
            String currentDate = ("Date: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year);

            setFont(myFont);

            Graphics2D screen2D = (Graphics2D) screen;
            screen2D.drawString(greeting, 20, 50);
            screen2D.drawString(currentTime, 20, 75);
            screen2D.drawString(currentDate, 20, 100);

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks @LuxxMiner. I knew I had been doing something wrong, just not sure what.